# Oracle Database JRE location check

Tags: java, oracle, jvm, oracle10g

Can someone tell me, where can I check which JRE (I need the folder) runs on my computer, when I try to call a java method from Oracale Database (from a PLSQL block)? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It will use either `$ORACLE_HOME/jre`, or `$ORACLE_HOME/jdk/jre`.

Those are on the server, as Java (and PL/SQL) runs in the database, not in your client.

It isn't clear if 'on my computer' refers to your client machine or the server machine (if they aren't the same). The version of Java on the client machine may be important for the client itself - e.g. SQL Developer needs certain versions - but it will have no effect on Java code running in the database, via Java stored procedures; and those can't see additional jars installed on the client machine.

Comment: My computer in this case means the server; I had to set certain providers for the JRE, and my test program ran from command line, but didn' ran from the database. I thought, maybe I was setting the providers on the wrong JRE.